# Could someone please explain the Matrix (Mr.Anderson)?

Tags: java, android, matrix, bitmap

I'm pretty new to manually manipulating images, so please bear with me.

I have an image that I'm allowing the user to shrink/grow and move around.

The basic behavior works perfectly. However, I need to be able to grab whatever is in the "viewport" (visible clipping region rectangle) and save it out as a separate bitmap.

Before I can do this, I need to get a fix on WHERE the image actually is and what is being displayed. This is proving more tricky than I would have imagined.

My problem is that the Matrix documentation is absurdly vague, and I'm lost as to how I can measure the coordinates and dimensions of my transformed image.  As I see it, the X,Y of the image remain constant even as the user shrinks/grows it.  So, even though it reports at being at 0,0 it's displayed at (say) 100,100.  And the only way I can get those coordinates is to do a fairly ugly computation (again... I'm probably not doing it the most elegant way, since geometry is not my forte).

I'm kind of hoping that I'm missing something and that there's some way to pull the object's auto translated coordinates and dimensions.

in an ideal world I would be able to call (pseudo) `myImg.getDisplayedWidth()` and `myImg.getDisplayedX()`.

Oh, and I should add that this may all be a problem that I'm causing myself by using the center of the image as the point from which to grow/shrink.  If I left the default 0,0 coordinate as the non changing point, I think the location would be correct no matter what its size was.  So... maybe the answer to all this is to simply figure out my center offset and apply that to my translations?

All help greatly appreciated (and people not arbitrarily messing with my question's title even more so!).

Comment: To clarify: Do you have the Matrix that is being applied to the image, as well as the original image points? Also, is this `android.graphics.Matrix` or `android.opengl.Matrix`?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the first question. I'm not using opengl.  I have a Bitmap that is being drawn to a Canvas in a View. The View is set as a child to a layout with its clipChildren set to "true".  I'm don't know what you mean by "original image points".  I'm placing the image myself. Currently I'm having to translate where I have to move the image to so that it shows up in the viewport, since right off the bat it's being displayed at about .3 scale.  I'm using a point in the center of the image when I scale it, so it grows from the middle outward.

Comment: so, as it grows it's reported X,Y are static even though it's upper left hand corner is moving as the user pinches.

Comment: So how are you translating the Bitmap currently, so that the View displays it at the size you want? Are you using the Matrix class to do the translation?

Comment: I like the previous funny title, Mr Anderson :)

Comment: I didn't change the title!!! Oddly, there is no credit give for who did... very interesting...

Comment: @Bringer128, yeah, I'm calling setScale(sx,sy, px,py) on my matrix object. px and py are the center of the bitmap... I think I'm close to figuring this out... I had a eureka moment when I realized that it was this center offset business that was causing me all my grief, though I'd still like to think that I'm doing this the *hard way, and that there are more elegant pre-built objects to help handle all this.

Comment: @Dr.Dredel The change history shows who removed it. Just click the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/8178667/revisions)

Comment: Andrew Marshall? Why would he go messing with my title? And who is he? He also removed my "all help appreciated" line at the end... what gives?

Comment: @Dr.Dredel So, if you have the original untranslated position of the Bitmap (x, y, width, height) then can't you just pass each of the 4 points into the Matrix using the mapPoints(float[], float[]) method?

Comment: maybe! is that what mapPoints is for? This is the part where the documentation totally fails me... Did they just omit describing it because it's a generic class that's been covered a million times in other docs? Offhand it's not obvious what mapPoints does.

Comment: @Dr.Dredel The documentation for the `map*` methods says "apply this matrix to..." which appears to be what you're looking for.

Comment: Unfortunately, no one can be told what the matrix is, you have to see it for yourself.

Comment: @Dr.Dredel See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64082/why-do-people-keep-editing-my-questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Matrix method [`mapPoints(float[] dst, float[] src)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html#mapPoints%28float%5B%5D,%20float%5B%5D%29) can be used to get a series of translated points by applying the Matrix translation. Or in (slightly) more layman's terms, an instance of the Matrix class contains not only the translation instruction but also convenience methods to apply the Matrix translation to a series of points.

So in your case, you just need the corners of your untranslated Bitmap (x, y, width, height) and pass the corner points into that method to get the translated points.

Comment: you rock.  So, I'm trying out the RectF flavor and it's getting me the x,y correctly but showing the w,h as 0.  I can probably just use it as is (cause it's easy to get the true width by just multiplying the original W * the scale, but I'm curious what you mean by "passing the bitmap" into the matrix. I don't see a signature that takes a bitmap param, so, I'm unclear on how you mean for me to do that.  I'll give you the checkmark anyway, since you got me 99% of the way home. :)

Comment: @Dr.Dredel Oops, that was a grammar fail. It should have been "them" instead of "it". How's it look now?

Comment: @Dr.Dredel When constructing your RectF, are you getting it by going `new RectF(bitmapX, bitmapY, bitmapX + bitmap.getWidth(), bitmapY + bitmap.getHeight())`?

Comment: no, I was just calling the default (empty) constructor... I'll try it the way you describe above to see if that gives it that last bit of oomph. Otherwise it's working perfectly! thanks again.